# FreeBSD based routers

Tags: freebsd, opensource-projects, router

I am looking for a `FreeBSD` based wireless router to hack around it and also use it at home.

I saw some listed on www.bsdrouter.org but those seem outdated.

Can someone point me to such a product/project which is ongoing?

My motive is to learn hacking on this device.

Comment: Are you looking for software or hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for software, your best choice is probably [pfSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PfSense). You could also choose [m0n0wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M0n0wall).

If you're looking for hardware, see the pfSense list [list of hardware vendors](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=44&Itemid=50). Both m0n0wall and pfSense will run on the [ALIX.2D13](http://store.netgate.com/-P40.aspx) board.

Answer (score 2):

[ZRouter.org is a FreeBSD based firmware for embedded devices](http://zrouter.org/), a rather new project, you'll find [more information in FreeBSD's Quarterly Status Report](http://www.freebsd.org/news/status/report-2011-07-2011-09.html#ZRouter.org-project-%E2%80%94-a-FreeBSD-based-firmware-for-embedded%0A------devices). (It supports ARM-based devices.)

Also note that the [BSD magazine](http://bsdmag.org/magazine) recently had some related articles, they covered the NanoBSD scripts using an ALIX platform, for example. (It's free to download if they get your mail address.)